# Django sql query

Tags: sql, django

I understand that there is an option to write directly queries in SQL when write in Django... I do not understand why use it and how? maybe example will help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. if you want more performance, you can use raw SQL queries in Django.
2. use it only when you can not do task with which Django QuerySet.

example: 
model.py:
class employee(models.Model):

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
position = models.CharField(max_length=20)
sal = models.IntegerField()
```

SQL query same to  same as model_name.objects.all() : 
emp_list=employee.objects.raw('select * FROM blogapp_employee')